# File handling with windows forms in c#

Tags: c#

I'm using windows form in c# to write data into a text file. I can't able to display information from the list pets to the listbox and save it to a text file.

Can anyone help?

Here is the question:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>();

        pets.Add(new Pet("Rex", 4, 500.00));
        pets.Add(new Pet("Mittens", 2, 125.50));
        pets.Add(new Pet("Clifford", 7, 30.00));

        writePets(pets);
    }

    
    private void writePets(List<Pet> pets)
    {
        foreach(var a in pets)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(a);
        }
        //listBox1.DataSource = pets;
        ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName);
            listBox1.DataSource = pets;
            sw.Close();
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: So I need to display information from the list pets (Rex, Mittens ,Clifford) into the listBox and save that data from listbox into a file but I'm getting unhandled exception

Comment: what's the message of the exception? Which line in the code throws the exception? What steps you are performing that results in exception?

Comment: Exception Unhandled

System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'

Exception is when I use for each loop to add items to listbox

Comment: You have `listBox1.Items.Add(a);`, `listBox1.Items.Add(line);` and `listBox1.DataSource = pets;` in `writePets` method.. Looks like you are trying to do multiple things in one single method.... what exactly you want to do in this method?

Comment: basically, I wanted to add the data from the list into the file so what I was trying to do is adding that data into listbox and then save it into a textfile

Comment: Why not add directly from `pets` list to the file? Why you want to add it to ListBox? Why are you adding items to the list again and again? You are reading from the file and writing to the file also... If you want to write to the file then why do `SteamReader`? Just loop thru the `pets` list and write to the file using StreamWriter...

Comment: Yep I tried with the StreamWriter to add the list into the file but that didn't  work

Comment: Do you have any other method which can be quite helpful?

Comment: Do you want to take the items of a list box into a text file ? or get data from a text file into a list box?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the other problems with your code I think what should answer your question is that in the stream writer you need to create a loop that will go through each list box item and write it to the text file.

```
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName);

            foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(listBoxItem.ToString());
            }
            
           
            sw.Close();
        }
```

But take some time to work on the way you are populating your list box. The error you are getting is probably due to you trying to add records to the list box in different manners and its probably not liking it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just make WritePets do one thing, and do it fairly well. This is how we should write our methods in c#; a method named WritePets (note the pascal case) should write the pets to disk, only. It shouldn't show them in a list, it shouldn't read pets. If you want to show pets, make a ShowPets, if you want to read pets make a ReadPets; there is no penalty for making more methods

```
private void WritePets(List<Pet> pets)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    if(sfd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
      return;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    //build the string we will write to the file
    for each(var p in pets)
      sb.AppendFomat("{0},{1},{2:F2}", p.Name, p.Age, p.Weight).AppendLine();

    File.AppendAllText(sb.ToString(), sfd.FileName); 
}
```

Please note, because I strongly suspect that this is homework the code above contains 3 deliberate, but minor, errors that I'd like you to fix so that you think about the code rather than just paste in. One of them will probably require taking a quick look at the documentation for File.

There is also a good chance that I've guessed the names of the properties of a pet incorrectly (like that 500 isn't the pet's weight..) which you'll need to patch up. If you don't want a csv you can adjust the format of a line by tweaking the placeholder string in the AppendFormat call